# For each loop prints array as well as array values

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, foreach

I have a for each loop in a wordpress site that outputs content for use in structured data. This mostly works fine, but I am seeing the actual array being output as well as the values values from it.

So I have the following:

```
"@context" : "http://schema.org",
"@type": ["ItemList", "events"],
"name": "<?php the_title(); ?>",
"url": "<?php echo $current_url ?>",
"itemListElement": [
$args = array( 
        'numberposts'       => -1, 
        'post_type'         => 'events', 
        'post_status'       => 'publish',
        'orderby'           => 'date', 
        'order'             => 'DESC', 
        'meta_query' => array(
            array(
                'key' => 'event_end_date',
                'compare' => '>=',
                'value' => $today
            )
        ),
        'meta_key' => 'event_start_date'
    );
    $myposts = get_posts($args);
    foreach ($myposts as $mypost) { 
        $args[] = 
        '{
            "@type": "ListItem",
            "item": {
                "@type": "Event",
                "name": "' . get_the_title($mypost->ID) . '",
                "location": "' . get_field( 'event_address', $mypost->ID) . '",
                "startDate": "' . get_field( 'event_start_date', $mypost->ID ) . '",
                "endDate": "' . get_field( 'event_end_date', $mypost->ID ) . '",
                "description": "' . get_the_excerpt($mypost->ID) . '"
            }
        }';
    }   
    echo implode( ', ', $args );
```

And this outputs:

```
"@context" : "http://schema.org",
"@type": ["ItemList", "events"],
"name": "Forthcoming Shows",
"url": "http://localhost/forthcoming-shows/",
"itemListElement": [
-1, events, publish, date, DESC, Array, event_start_date, {  // this should be just the curly brace
    "@type": "ListItem",  
    "item": {  
        "@type": "Event",  
        "name": "name here", 
        "location": "this is the address",  
        "startDate": "25/06/2020",
        "endDate": "25/06/2020",
        "description": "some description"
    }
}, {
    "@type": "Event",  
        "name": "Another event", 
        "location": "an address",  
        "startDate": "25/06/2020",
        "endDate": "25/06/2020",
        "description": "some description"
    }
}]
```

Why am I gettng the array printing above the results?
I am also gettng an error message "Notice:  Array to string conversion in ... on line 214. Which refers to the echo implode line. Not entirely sure if thats related.

Comment: Never manually craft your json strings.  Use `json_encode()` or suffer headache gains and hair loss.

Comment: Build your complete multi-dimensional data structure, then json_encode it just once when you are done modifying it.  It couldn't be simpler.  You were heading down a nasty path. :)

Comment: Thanks @mickmackusa I will have to look into that. It will hopefully help a lot with this structued data malarky. I'm still interested to know what's going on here though

Answer (score 0):

The first key of the array it's:

```
$args = array( 
        'numberposts'       => -1, 
        'post_type'         => 'events', 
        'post_status'       => 'publish',
        'orderby'           => 'date', 
        'order'             => 'DESC', 
        'meta_query' => array(
            array(
                'key' => 'event_end_date',
                'compare' => '>=',
                'value' => $today
            )
        ),
        'meta_key' => 'event_start_date'
    );
```

So, when you do the implode, the "meta_query" key as an array. 
That's why it shows you an array when you print it. If you want to convert that array into a string, you could do a json_encode of it (before the implode):

```
        'meta_query' => json_encode(array(
            array(
                'key' => 'event_end_date',
                'compare' => '>=',
                'value' => $today
            )
        )),
```

That depending on what you want to do with that array.You have to solve the nesting yourself.

---

EDIT: (based on comments)

You have an array of associative arrays on meta_query. So, that gonna print an array of objects. If you want to delete the two levels of the array, you can do it:

```
$args = array( 
        'numberposts'       => -1, 
        'post_type'         => 'events', 
        'post_status'       => 'publish',
        'orderby'           => 'date', 
        'order'             => 'DESC', 
        'meta_query' => json_encode(
            array(
                'key' => 'event_end_date',
                'compare' => '>=',
                'value' => $today
            )
        ),
        'meta_key' => 'event_start_date'
    );
```

This will gonna to print a json object. If you expect to print an object of objects, then you would have to include the array inside in an associative array:

```
$args = array( 
        'numberposts'       => -1, 
        'post_type'         => 'events', 
        'post_status'       => 'publish',
        'orderby'           => 'date', 
        'order'             => 'DESC', 
        'meta_query' => json_encode(array(
            'mykey' => array(
                'key' => 'event_end_date',
                'compare' => '>=',
                'value' => $today
            )
        )),
        'meta_key' => 'event_start_date'
    );
```

But it all depends on what you want to do with that array...

Comment: This is great in that it resolves the error message "Notice: Array to string conversion in ... on line 214". The downside is that it still prints the array. Although now it prints this portion as json. Whic I can sort of understand.
 `-1, events, publish, date, DESC, Array, event_start_date, {` has become `-1, events, publish, date, DESC, [{"key":"event_end_date","compare":">=","value":"20200615"}], event_start_date, {` when what I was hoping for/expecting was just `{`